# Why do Ethiopian Jews who practice Haymanot Judaism still have roles like Nabiyy (Prophet) or Kahen or Kes (Priest)? How are they allowed this?

Tags: history, talmud-gemara, kohen-priest, ethiopian-beta-israel

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but since the destruction of the Second Temple, (G-d, blessed be He, forbid), the roles such as that of a Priest/High Priest and the like, were removed and similar practiced stopped. Rabbinical authorities, who have already been on the rise prior to this, took over from there to continue the truthful practices in an appropriate manner.

If this is correct, then why do Ethiopian Jews still have roles such as:

- Nabiyy (Prophet)
- Monkosa (Monk)
- Kahen or Kes (Priest/spiritual leader similar to Kohen and analogous to Rabbi or Hakham)
- Liqa Kahnet (High Priest)
- Debtera (itinerant holy man)
- Shmagle (elder)

I've never seen some of these like a Monk/Solitary man, and have read that Rabbis generally discouraged such activity of getting away from the community and being solitary, but apparently Beta Israel doesn't follow the Talmud or the Oral Law.

By continuing to have, for instance, a High Priest, are Ethiopian Jews breaking any laws since Jews shouldn't have a High Priest if they don't have the Temple, etc.? Why do they still have such roles, and are so different from all the other Jewish communities even in the books they regard as authoritative?

Comment: As you have stated yourself, the kahen is a spiritual leader akin to a rabbi. The Liqa Kahnet is similar to a chief rabbi. Neither were intended to replace kohanim descended from Aharon; their roles are community-centered, not temple-centered. That said, there was great reluctance on the part of the Israeli Chief Rabbinate to recognize the legitimacy of the Ethiopian religious leadership when they began making aliyah.

Comment: @RabbiKaii What is gadol-adar? I apologize if I posted this question in the wrong place, I'm still pretty new here.

Comment: @Harel13 Thank you for your explanation. I was just a bit thrown off by the usage of labels like "High Priest" for what seems to be non-temple/post-temple Jewish community.

Comment: For thousands of years, Ethiopian Jews were cut off from Miami Beach and had no place to dispose of their elders. The Shmagles therefore just remain with the rest of the community and interact with them every day, not just when they send birthday or Chanukah money.

Comment: @RabbiKaii No questions are "decided" here. This is just a forum to help find answers that are out there. So if a posek wrote a teshuva on the topic, it could be brought as an answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what category this falls under, but IMO, this question should be closed.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Are you literally stalking my profile? Mind your own business. This was a legitimate question, looking for a legitimate answer about the customs & nomenclature of a Jewish sect/group. You haven't provided a reason for why the question should be closed at all, so leave it.

Comment: @setszu Absolutely not. It popped up in the new questions list. In general, the subject of the Jews from Ethiopian background interests me. They have a very precious tradition and are recognized within Torah literature for over a millennia, perhaps even longer. Many of the assumptions you are making in your question are wrong and the tone is derogatory toward the Jewish Ethiopian community. We are one people  and every tradition is precious beyond words.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Ok I apologize. In terms of my question, I had zero intent of anything derogatory towards anyone. I was scared that they are basically having a "temple" with "priests" but without the temple being the 3rd Temple in the Holy Land, so I wanted to know if this breaks any laws and why their practices are so different. I already said "please correct me if I'm wrong" in my question, and gave the context, so I'm not sure where you're getting a derogatory tone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many of these roles are not practiced in the way you assume. A priest in the Ethiopian tradition is a role closer to a Rabbi than to a Priest in the times of the Temple. The Ethiopian Jewish tradition as it exists now seems to have developed separate from having a codified Talmud from Babylon or Israel.

We know the Ethiopian Jewish community has existed for a long time as they come in and out of history, and during the times of the Radbaz they were well known and he accepted them as Jewish. But we lack historical documentation about their development and beliefs. It's a similar situation to the Sadducees. We know they existed, we know they were a dedicated group that was separate from other groups. But we truly only know what everyone else said about them as we lack any first hand knowledge or documentation from them.

Comment: the first half of your answer is accurate, eloquent, and well sourced. The second half of your answer, however, is not befitting a man of your stature, particularly one who bears the name of our beloved *rodef shalom*.

Comment: Instead of a polemic, why not add in an excerpt from Rav Obadiah Yosef's ruling affirming the historical existence of the Beta Israel community and their unbroken mesorah to the tribe of Dan in the time of Shlomo HaMelech?

Comment: @יהושעק I didn't make the polemic, someone of another answer did. And I think it is not befitting a website of our stature for someone to answer this question with a quote stating the Jewishness of Ethiopians is fiction. As long as that quote remains up as an answer, my polemic response will remain. If someone wants to ask me why I singled out Ashkenazim, it's because it's much more common to hear things like Ethiopian Jewishness is fiction amongst Ashkenazim than it is any other Jewish group.

Comment: @יהושעק  And while I would love to quote Ovadia Yosef talking about the Mesorah of Ethiopian Jews and their connection to Dan, I will not do so. Because I can't prove it anymore than Ovadia Yosef could have. We don't have enough evidence for me to state such a thing as a fact. But if people are going to look at how Ethiopian Jewishness "diverges" and then try and say that's proof of Ethiopians not having a true mesorah, then I will die on the hill of pointing out that none of us will truly pass such a test.

Comment: "Despite the unequivocal declaration of Radbaz with regard to the origins of the Falasha community, Radbaz' halakhic decision, handed down in the sixteenth century, may not be valid in the twentieth. In the course of the intervening four centuries it is entirely possible that there has been extensive intermarriage between the Falashas and the indigenous Abyssinian population." [Rabbi J.D. Bleich, Contemporary Halakhic Problems, Vol I, Part II, CHAPTER XIV] [Available on Sefaria]

Comment: Note: The quote I posted does NOT state the **Jewishness** of Ethiopians is fiction. He merely posits that there remains a **doubt**. Most Israelites can prove their connection, by virtue of showing that their ancestors were people who were presumed to have been Israelites. However no such connection, or presumption of connection, exists for the so-called Ethiopian Jews. As for so-called Jewish practices by mainstream Jews, I would agree that some of those **practices** might be questionable, but they don't impugn the core **lineage** of those practitioners, which is presumed to be 100% Jewish

Comment: Radbaz proves that connection. Even when Ethiopian Jewish ships would randomly arrive in ports they would be wearing tzitzit. Their oral history posits their Israelite lineage. It doesn't matter that some of them married Christians. Most Jewish groups have. Even genetic tests shows Ashkenazim descend by male semitic DNA but mostly local European women who would have been Christian.

Comment: @IsraelReader But also, this question isn't about whether Ethiopian Jews are or are not Jewish. So while you are using that source to strengthen your overall argument, the source posits its own argument that many would find offensive.

Comment: @IsraelReader I understand that when reading the entirety of your source's work, that it may not come across as him declaring them as fiction. But your quote, taken without context from his work certainly comes across that way with the statement: "To imagine that we are dealing with another tradition of Judaism is pure fiction." That's some strong language right there, especially when that wasn't even the question. You could start your quote one sentence later and lose nothing other than a polemic.

Comment: Rabbi J. D. Bleich already pointed out that even if we were to fully accept Radbaz's halakhic decision, the question still remains if that decision is still relevant some 450 years later.

Comment: @IsraelReader So in other words you're going to double down on your quote?

Comment: If you take down your polemic against Ashkenazim, I will try to revise my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145745/discussion-between-aaron-and-israelreader).